# JavaScript/CSS Show respective div on click from grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron, grid

I have a working grid that show a cell for every title in the json:

```
async function loop_iteration(json, i, arr) {
    arr.push(`<a onClick="show()" class="cell" id=${i}"><div >${json[i].title}</div> </a>`)
    arr.push(`<div class="info" id=${i}>${json[i].title}<br><br><br><br><br>Game Size: ${json[i].size}<br><br>Last Update: ${json[i].date}</div>`)

}
```

I want to show on click of  the class info.

The problem is that it gives always the same title(first), it's like is always the first cell to be clicked

I show the info div like this:

```
 <script>
      function showinfo() {
      var node = document.querySelector('.cell.info')
      var visibility = node.style.visibility;
      node.style.visibility = visibility == "visible" ? 'hidden' : "visible"
      }
    </script>
```

while if i show the div using this:

```
function show(){
        var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
        for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++)
        {
        divsToHide[i].style.visibility="visible";
        }

        //document.getElementsByClassName('info')['${i}'].style.visibility = 'visible';
    


      }
```

happen something strange, the div showed is not the first but is like it show all the div

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem.
It was the javascript, so i extract the id  and then iterate the class with the id

```
    function show(clicked_id){
    clicked_id = parseFloat(clicked_id);
    document.getElementsByClassName('info')[clicked_id].style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
```